# cf for countable limit ordinal

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

My question is related to the cofinality for ordinal number. We know $cf(c)>\omega$ , $cf(\alpha)=1$  for any successor ordinal. I am trying to show the $cf(\alpha)=\omega$ for any limit ordinal  $\alpha<\omega_1.$ my guess this can be done by constructed a cofinal map. Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Any countable number less than $\omega$ is finite and a successor, so $cf(\alpha)=1$ for $\alpha \lt \omega$

Comment: You probably meant to write that $\mathrm{cf}(\alpha)=\omega$ for any countable limit ordinal.

Comment: A countable ordinal can't have cofinality bigger than $\omega$ just by cardinality reasons. Can you show that if a total order has finite cofinality it must be $1$? Can you show that an ordinal of cofinality $1$ is a successor?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Just by cardinality? I don't see how - the cofinality is an ordinal, and there are certainly for example countable ordinals larger than $\omega$.

Comment: Surely "for any countable $\alpha<\omega$" should be "for any countable limit ordinal $\alpha$"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The cofinality can be defined to be either an ordinal or a cardinal, it makes no difference (assuming choice of course), I usually define it as a cardinal, which is why I assumed OP's definition to also be a cardinal, but I agree that if cofinality is defined as an ordinal some extra argument is needed

Comment: Sorry from all of you for the typos. I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

Asking about countable $\alpha<\omega$ doesn't make much sense; surely the actual question is to show that any countable limit ordinal has cofinality $\omega$.

For the revised version, it's clear that the cofinality cannot be finite so we need only show it's no larger than $\omega$. Since $\alpha$ is countable we can write $$\alpha=\{a_j:j\in\omega\}.$$Since $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, if $F\subset\alpha$ is finite there exists $x\in\alpha$ with $x>y$ for all $y\in F$.

So we can define $f:\omega\to\alpha$ by saying that $f(n)$ is the smallest element of the set $\{x\in\alpha: x>a_j,0\le j\le n\}$. It's clear that $f$ is cofinal.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.